# How to save an entity for operations such as voting

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

let's take a youtube video page for example. after the page is rendered. you can upvote or downvote the video, and comment.

I'm having a similar case here. where an article is displayed with it's title and body(text). and I want to add the option for user so that they can vote. Two  Entity looks like this:

```
public class Article implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;

    private User from;

    private String title;

    private String body;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "article")
    private List<VoteArticle> votes = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
public class VoteArticle implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Article_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Article article;
```

and I have jsf view that have a view param as the article's id `article.xhtml?t=4`
before rendering the view I look up and setup the article in the RequestScoped Bean (ArticleBean), then The view is rendered.

now as we all know since the bean is @RequestScoped all fields are re-initiliazed for every next request. So My question is, Do I need to get the article entity from the database every time I need to make an operation (voting, commenting) or is there a better way?

Right now my solution is to take the parameter view ".xhtml?**t**" and make a new Article entity, set its Id and use it.

Is something wrong with my solution? how do you implement such case? Thanks.

Comment: Why not use ViewScoped?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like setting your controller code to @ViewScoped instead of @RequestScoped would solve your problem.

You could make a method init() and give it a @PostConstruct annotation.  Within init() you can pull your Article object from the database.  Because the controller is view scoped these objects will stay until the user leaves the page.

You can call methods like voteUp() voteDown() on your ViewScoped controller via ajax calls and modify your Article object without having to pull it fresh from the DB each time.

Comment: Thanks for replying, ok I will try with viewscoped